# Is the Slave 1 not a Firespray?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-edge-of-the-empire

I've tried to rebuild the *Slave 1* from its [wikia entry](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Slave_I) but ran into the problem that I didn't have nearly enough hardpoints to build it on the Firespray chassis.

Am I overlooking something here? Or should I see the *Slave 1* as its own type of ship instead of a modified Firespray?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**In the canon (and in boardgames and rpgs) *Slave 1* is considered a heavily modified Firespray-31**

Basically Boba Fett spent a lot of time and money modifying and updating *Slave 1*. This would account for it having more hard points than a typical Firespray-31 would for all of the weapon systems *Slave 1* has demonstrated.

**Within the rules you could either make it a completely custom ship or you could make the closest thing possible based on the Firespray-31 chassis, the choice is ultimately up to you.**

The first option highlights the individual nature of the ship and puts the prospects of the players getting their hands on something similar out of reach, however you will be out there on your own and not be able to rely on the Firespray-31 as a guideline. The latter meanwhile might limit the fidelity of your version of the ship, but ultimately provide you firmer ground to operate on.

Answer (score 5):

The Wikia entry for *Slave I* you're looking at is inaccurate because it lists everything ever written about that ship, especially in novels that are not canon at all.

You can build a very faithful *Attack of the Clones* version of *Slave I* within the rules and the listed number of hard points (HPs) of the Firespray: switch the tractor beam for the concussion missile (0 HP), 2 medium/heavy laser cannons (2 HPs), 1 minelayer (1 HP), and the last HP is probably an upgraded Ion engine 'cause *Slave I* seems to easily keep up with Obi-Wan's figher at full speed.

Now you have a fully faithful movie *Slave I*.

If you decide to add 1 more HP with Tinkerer you can even get the hyperdrive generator and improve the *Slave I* hyperdrive to a more advanced class 1.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately they haven't put the ability to add more hard points to a ship into the game yet. The closest they came to it was the Age of Rebellion: Stay on Target book. The Ace class Rigger career allows you to pick a signature ship for like 15 xp. Which allows you to upgrade all mechanics checks on the signature ship. Though I don't consider these guys to be good pilots though they can certain able to fly a ship. They should be your secondary gunner and mechanic not your pilot.

I also would say slave 1 is a NPC ship it doesn't have to follow all the rules. I highly doubt you can build the Falcon either with all the things that Han did to it over the years.

Answer (score -2):

IMO, it's an NPC ship, so the standard PC rules don't apply.

But if you did want to build it as a PC ship, then you could apply the various talents from AoR Rigger in addition to other Technician or Bounty Hunter talents, and you could get there.

Comment: The problem with that approach is. Players tend to try to salvage things and if its better than their playtools they will just take it for themselves. so it would always become a pc ship if they are playing their chars intelligent

Comment: Don't let the players take it, if you don't want them to have it.  As the GM, what they do or do not get is entirely up to you.

Comment: The problem with that is that if players do something that you don't think of (instead of shooting a ship down, they board it) and manage to do all things correct it would end up in railroading or worse if you try to still not let them have it (or if you "cripple" the ship by then in converting it so that it is rule conform). I've seen that in action as a player myself and there is almost nothing I hated more. Thus as a gm I tend to avoid that (which is the reason I only give npcs things that pcs also could have regardless of system played)

Comment: In the case of the Slave-1, I think it's close enough to a standard Firespray that your game probably wouldn't be over-balanced if the players did get their hands on it.  If those minor differences do end up seriously imbalancing the game, then I think you've got bigger problems.  At the end of the day, this is supposed to be a narrative game where the GM and the players collaborate to try to have the Most Fun creating the Most Awesomest Story, and you shouldn't be getting bogged down in minor details like this.  But that's just IMO, and YMMV.